# Checkbox unticks automatically

Tags: php, checkbox

When I execute my page, I tick in a checkbox. And when I send, my checkbox unticks automatically!! Why?

```
<?php
require ("connexion.php");
$reqSQL="SELECT DISTINCT port FROM plante";
$result=$connexion->query($reqSQL) or DIE("Erreur dans la requêteSQL '$reqSQL'");
$ligne=$result->fetch();
echo "<p> <center>";
echo "<h3>Port plante</h3>";
while($ligne != false)
{
    echo '<table style="width:300px">';
    echo '<tr>';
    $port=$ligne["port"];
//my checkbox ticks when i click on it, and when i go to the next page it becomes untick.

    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='port' name='port[]' value='$port'/>$port</br></td>";
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
    $ligne= $result->fetch();

}
echo "</center></p>";
$result->closeCursor();
$connexion = null;
?>
```

Comment: As far as the browser is concerned, the page loaded after you submit is a second page, with a second checkbox; it's up to you to make it pre-checked based on whatever logic you want.

Comment: Do you mean that it is unchecked after the page re-renders (which is what is supposed to happen), or that the form submission doesn't include the value of the checkbox (which means something is broken)?

Answer (score 0):

```
put this in your line checked="checked"
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='port' name='port[]' value='$port' 
checked="checked" />$port</br></td>";
```

Comment: Actually, i can't add "checked" to that line because, my sql line is supposed to bring multiples lines form my database. If i add "checked" then all chechbox will be checked! I want to leave the user to selected the option.